# Why am I able to directly use some of the ruby C extension array methods, but not others?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am using many of the array methods found in array.c of the ruby codebase, but when trying to call

```
VALUE rIntersection = rb_ary_and(rAry1, rAry2);
```

I got this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_and
  Referenced from: ./ext/ev/counters.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

In other areas of my code I am using rb_ary_sort_bang, rb_ary_clear, rb_ary_reverse, etc etc.  So I'm not sure why rb_ary_and is any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/array_8c-source.html (Line 2666)

There you can see that the method rb_ary_and is declared *static*. This means that it is only visible inside of *array.c*.

Comment: Is it considered bad form to just copy the array.c file into your project, and change the definitions to not being static?

Comment: @Jeremy Smith: If you notice on line 3042 of the same file, the function is used when the `&` method is invoked on the array. Why not try calling that method instead?

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes, that would be bad form and possibly a copyright problem, it would also tie you a specific version of Ruby as the array internals are likely to change. Instead, just call the methods using the standard API. Using the standard API also means that you should be able to work with subclasses that override `&`.

Comment: rAry1 & rAry2 doesn't work in C.  So how else would I call that method within C?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I would assume this would work:

`rb_funcall( rAry1, rb_intern("&"), 1, rAry2 )`